# Nice output of grep within for loop

Tags: grep, tcsh

I am using simple grep like

```
grep -E "input files : 0" *.stdout
```

and its output is following:

```
QCD_HT200to300_13TeV_ext.stdout:==> Total number of input files : 0
WJetsToLNu_HT_600To800_13TeV_ext1.stdout:==> Total number of input files : 0
```

If I use the same grep command within the for loop then its output is not nice. My script is

```
 foreach file ( `grep -E "input files : 0" *.stdout` )
         echo $file
 end
```

the output of this is like:

```
QCD_HT200to300_13TeV_ext.stdout:==>
Total
number
of
input
files
:
0
WJetsToLNu_HT_600To800_13TeV_ext1.stdout:==>
Total
number
of
input
files
:
0
```

How I can get the same output within `foreach` loop as I get from `grep` command running independently.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters

Comment: @Sundeep: I looked at link and tried but it did not worked... But, the suggestation given by JDQ worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the list of files to iterate through in the foreach loop and do the grep inside the foreach loop.

```
set files = `ls *.stdout`

foreach file ( $files )
   grep -E "input files : 0” $file
end
```